# Where did the index of a subgroup notation $[G:H]$ begin to be used?

Tags: mathematics, notation, abstract-algebra, group-theory

In texts of algebra, the cardinality of cosets is written in $[G:H]$ or $|G:H|$. Where did this notation originate?

The history about $G/H$ can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/857539/who-named-quotient-groups). $[G:H]$ is called [index of a subgroup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index_of_a_subgroup). But I'm not sure what advantage this notation has. I think $|G/H|$ can also be used when $G/H$ is not a group or has an infinite index.